# A red hard ball vs A hard red ball

Tags: adjectives

> We are playing with a red hard ball.
>
> We are playing with a hard red ball.

Can we use both 'red hard ball' and 'hard red ball'? Are they both correct or one of them is correct? I think both *hard red ball* and *red hard ball* are interchangeable.

Comment: https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the second sentence is correct, the first one sounds odd to my ears. When we use more than one adjective before a noun, there is often a preferred order of those adjectives. In this case, the correct order is:

**•** a hard red ball. (= quality + colour + noun)

Comment: Why not give the 'preferred order'? general opinion, specific opinion, size, shape, age, colour, nationality, material

Comment: Thank you Michael for elaborating the meaning. It helped a lot